# Show that any model of $\Delta$ is a Nonstandard Model of Arithmetic

Tags: logic, proof-verification, model-theory, solution-verification

I was hoping that someone could help check my proof. I originally thought I was spot of with my proof, but my professor suggested that my method was wrong. So, I went to check the hint in the back of the book, but the hint seemed like it was just my solution. He may have misunderstood me or I could have not said what I mean. Hence, I was hoping someone here could help me check it. Any help at all would be much appreciated! I will state the problem, then show my proof.

By true arithmetic we mean the set Γ of all sentences of the language of arithmetic that are true in the standard interpretation. By a nonstandard model of arithmetic we mean a model of this $\Gamma$  that is not isomorphic to the standard interpretation. Let $\Delta$ be the set of the sentences obtained by adding the sentences $c\not = \boldsymbol 0 $, $c\not = \boldsymbol 1 $, $c\not = \boldsymbol 2 $, and so on, to $\Gamma$. Show that any model of $\Delta$ would give us a nonstandard model of arithmetic.

Proof: Let $N$ a model of $\Gamma$. Moreover, let $M$ be the model of $\Delta$. Now, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $N\cong M$.

Then, we can say that there is a bijection $\alpha :|N|\to |M|$ such that for all $c$ we have $\alpha (c_{N})=c_{M}$.

Now, if $c_{N}=\boldsymbol 2_{N}$, then $\alpha (\boldsymbol 2_{N})=c_{M}=\boldsymbol2_{M}$. However, we know that $c_{M} \not =\boldsymbol2_{M}$.

Thus, we have reached a contradiction and our interpretations are not isomorphic.

If I am wrong where did I mess up, and how bad is it?

Thanks again!

Comment: Pretty bad, dealing with $2$ is not enough. For a proof, take the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ and our model $M$, and let $\alpha$ be an isomorphism from $M$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Show that for all $n$, $\alpha$ must take the interpretation of $c$ to something other than $n$ for $n=0, S0,\dots$. This is impossible.  Your question did not ask for a proof that $\Delta$ has a model. That is straight Compactness.

Comment: Then can I use the same proof, and just say no matter what $c_{N}$ I choose $\alpha (c_{N}) \not = c_{M}$ because $c_{M}\not = n$ for any integer $n$? Am I still way off? :( The hint in our text said "If M is a model of Δ, and if $\alpha$ were an isomorphism from M to the standard model
N, what would be $\alpha(c_{M})$?"

Comment: Yes, exactly. We have to show (which is easy) that $\alpha(c_M)$ cannot be **any** of $0,1,2,\dots$ (or start at $1$ if, unusually, your book starts $\mathbb{N}$ at $1$).

Comment: Okay, just to clarify, I made $\alpha :|M|\to |N|$ whereas the book used $\alpha :|N|\to |M|$. This should not matter though correct? That is, I am asking if you were saying "Yes, exactly." to my statement or the book's hint?

Comment: The direction is unimportant, since we are assuming $\alpha$ is a bijection and reaching a contradiction. But it is probably better from the point of view of clarity to suppose that the mapping goes from $\mathbb{N}$ to $M$ and show that it cannot be surjective.

Comment: Understood. I was just double checking to make sure we were on the same page. I think I completely understand the structure of the proof. However, I did have just one last question. Why is it that we need to show  $\alpha (c_{N})\not = c_{M}$ for every $c$? By definition if it would isomorphic then this equality would hold for every  $c$, so shouldn't we be able to use just one $c$ to show that it doesn't work?

Comment: Noe that if we only have a finite number of axioms of the form $c\ne k$, say none with $k\gt 1000$, then we can mae a model in which $c$ is interpreted as $2015$. This model, restricted to the language of arithmetic, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Andre.... You are amazing! lol Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume $N\models \Gamma$ and $M\models \Delta$, then you cannot conclude that $N\not\cong M$, since of course $M\models \Gamma$ because $\Delta\supseteq \Gamma$.

Instead, the question is asking you to show that, if $M\models\Delta$, then $M\not\cong N$, where $N$ is the *standard* model of $\Gamma$ - that is, $N=(\mathbb{N}, +, \times, 0, <)$.

Except this isn't quite right! $\Gamma$ is a set of sentences in the language $\{+, \times, <, 0, c\}$, whereas the standard model $N$ of arithmetic is only a $\{+, \times, <, 0\}$-structure. What you're really being asked to show is that, for any $a\in N$, we have $$(\mathbb{N}, +, \times, 0, <, a)\not\cong M.$$

You've started on the right direction - you've shown that $a$ cannot be 2. The same argument will show that $a\not = n$ for any standard natural number $n$; but these are all the elements of $N$! So you're essentially already done.

Note that the nonstandard model of arithmetic arising from $M$ is the *reduct* of $M$ to the smaller language $\{+, \times, 0, <\}$ of arithmetic.