# Show non-standard interpretation on language of arithmetic s.t. for any formula, if $\mathcal{N} \vDash F(n)$, then $\mathcal{M} \vDash F[m]$

Tags: logic

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the language of arithmetic. Let $\Gamma$ be the set of sentences true in the standard interpretation $\mathcal{N}$ [natural numbers]. Let $F(x)$ be any formula. Show that if $\mathcal{N} \vDash F(n)$, for every numeral $n$, then there is a non-standard model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma$ and a non-standard number $m$ such that $\mathcal{M} \vDash F[m]$
>
> (Hint: use compactness)

The compactness theorem says that if every finite subset of a set of sentences has a model, then the whole set has a model. I'm not sure how that helps.

One common nonstandard interpretation is one with rational numbers $\mathcal{Q}$ instead of natural numbers. However, that is not a model for $\Gamma$. Consider the formula $\forall x \exists y (x < y \, \& \, \lnot \exists z (x < z \, \& \, z < y))$. That is true in $\mathcal{N}$ and therefore is in the set $\Gamma$ but it's not true in $\mathcal{Q}$.

What other kind of non-standard models for $\Gamma$ exist?

Can I get a hint on this?

EDIT: Revised with help from @Noah Schweber.

Comment: The rationals do **not** constitute a model of $\Gamma$: consider for example the sentence $\forall x,y\exists z(x<y\rightarrow x<z\wedge z<y)$. This is true in $\mathbb{Q}$ but false in $\mathbb{N}$. Incidentally it's worth noting that a much stronger result is true - if $\mathcal{N}\models F(m)$ for every numeral $m$, then $\mathcal{M}\models F(n)$ for **every** model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma$ and **every** element $n$ of $\mathcal{M}$, standard or nonstandard. The proof is much easier than applying compactness here; this is an oddly-posed exercise.

Comment: I'd revise the first part of your comment to suggest formula $\forall x \exists y (x < y \, \& \, \lnot \exists z (x < z \, \& \, z < y))$ which is in $\Gamma$ since it's true in $\mathcal{N}$ but it's not true in $\mathcal{Q}$, so $\mathcal{Q}$ would not be a model for $\Gamma$. What would be a non-standard model for $\Gamma$ then?

Comment: There's no need for revision - any sentence $\varphi$ which is true in $\mathcal{Q}$ but false in $\mathcal{N}$ immediately yields a sentence true in $\mathcal{N}$ (equivalently, in $\Gamma$) but false in $\mathcal{Q}$, namely its negation $\neg\varphi$. As to examples of nonstandard models, it turns out that [in a precise sense $\Gamma$ has *no* easy-to-describe nonstandard models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). Arguments about nonstandard models of arithmetic have to be somewhat abstract, for this reason.

Comment: Can you solve the problem and demonstrate a non-standard model $\mathcal{M}$ as specified?

Comment: See my answer for the proof of the stronger result, and a guess at what problem your professor actually had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set $\Gamma$ as defined in OP's post. Add to this a constant symbol $m$ and, for each numeral $i$, the axiom $m \neq i$. Also, add the axiom $F(m)$.

Show that any finite subset of these axioms is satisfiable (aka has a model). Then, apply the compactness theorem.

Comment: In the problem $F(x)$ is any formula. You can't declare an axiom on an arbitrary formula.

Comment: @clay I interpreted the problem as: for every formula $F(m)$ such that $N$ models $F(n)$ for all numerals $n$, show there is a model of $Gamma$ with a non-standard $m$ which models $F[m]$. But if you prefer, you can construct "one model to rule them all" by adding every statement of the form $F(m)$ as an axiom, when $F$ is any statement such that for all numerals $n$, $N$ models $F(n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Mark has provided what I suspect is the intended solution, namely a compactness argument. However, this is an odd problem - a much stronger statement is true, and compactness plays no role at all.

*(I'm assuming here that the existence of nonstandard models at all has already been established; if not, then of course compactness is needed but now there's no obvious reason for talking about a formula $F$.)*

---

Suppose $F$ is a formula such that, for every numeral $m$, we have $\mathcal{N}\models F(m)$. There is a **single** sentence $\varphi$ which captures this situation: $$\forall x(F(x)).$$ Since **every natural number has a corresponding numeral**, the assumption "$\mathcal{N}\models F(m)$ for every numeral $m$" is equivalent to "$\mathcal{N}\models\forall x(F(x))$."

So the sentence $\forall x(F(x))$ is in $\Gamma$. But then if $\mathcal{M}$ is any nonstandard model of $\Gamma$ we must have $\mathcal{M}\models\forall x(F(x))$, or put another way $\mathcal{M}\models F(a)$ for every $a\in\mathcal{M}$ (nonstandard or not). Consequently we have:

> Suppose $F$ is a formula such that, for every numeral $m$, we have $\mathcal{N}\models F(m)$. Then for **every** nonstandard model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma$ and **every** element $a$ of $\mathcal{M}$ we have $\mathcal{M}\models F(a)$.

This is a stronger result than what is claimed in the OP - the latter merely says that *some* nonstandard model has *some* nonstandard element satisfying $F$.

---

That said, there **is** a version of this problem which does use compactness:

> Suppose $\Theta$ is a first-order theory in the language of arithmetic which proves $m\not=n$ for all distinct numerals $m,n$, and $F$ is a formula in the language of arithmetic such that $\Theta\models F(m)$ for every numeral $m$. Show that there is an $\mathcal{M}\models\Theta$ with some $a\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\models a\not=m$ for every numeral $m$ but $\mathcal{M}\models F(a)$.

Basically, there is no version of arithmetic which "pins down" the numerals exactly. Here Mark's answer (with $\Theta$ replacing $\Gamma$) is exactly what does the job. I suspect your professor actually intended to ask this, or something like it, since here compactness really is necessary.

Comment: We are given sentence $\forall x (F(x))$ in $\Gamma$. Every model of $\Gamma$, by definition of being a model, makes true every sentence in $\Gamma$, including $\forall x (F(x))$. That's true, but that's not the question being asked. We have to demonstrate a non-standard model, not isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$, with some non-standard member, and demonstrate that it is a model for $\Gamma$.

Comment: It looks like you answered the same question with a very different answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142470/show-that-any-model-of-delta-is-a-nonstandard-model-of-arithmetic?rq=1

Comment: @clay **Any** nonstandard model of $\mathcal{N}$ at all (nonstandard *means* "not isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$") and *any* nonstandard element of that model will do the job, per my answer. I'm assuming you already know how to build nonstandard models of $\Gamma$; if not, then that does need to be added.

Comment: I do understand. *any* nonstandard model of $\Gamma$ is a model of $\Gamma$... That doesn't help. I have to show that one exists.

Comment: @clay That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that any nonstandard model of $\Gamma$ yields a nonstandard model of $\Gamma$ *with a nonstandard element satisfying $F$*. The latter is what your OP asks for. Do you know how to build nonstandard models of $\Gamma$ in the first place? (I was taking this for granted.)

Comment: No, I don't know how to build non-standard models of $\Gamma$. I think that's what the question is asking. I'm learning this material for the first time... Once you have a non-standard model for $\Gamma$, it seems rather obvious that the nonstandard model has a nonstandard element and then that must satisfy $\forall x (F(x))$ since it's a model.